# disable linting inside comments

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want eslint to stop linting inside comments // and /* */.

when in comments I want to have freedom to write as I please. (disable 80 char limitation ***etc..***)

that's pretty basic in my opinion and yet I can't find it anywhere, is there a predefined rule to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, to disable line length checking inside comments just use the following rule in your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
rules: {
    "max-len": ["warn", { "code": 80, "ignoreComments": true }]
}
```

This way ESLint will complain about lines with more than 80 characters only if they're not comments. Check the documentation for rule [max-len](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len) for more info.

Also notice that any ESLint rule you define for your project can be ignored in specific code blocks if you want, for example:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
YOUR LONG LINE HERE
/* eslint-enable max-len */
```

Comment: thanks, what if want to disable all rules inside comments?

Comment: I don't think you can do that using a rule, only way I'm aware is wrapping the code block in `/* eslint-disable */` and `/* eslint-enable */` (these will disable all rules).

Comment: the rule you suggested + this rule did the job for me: "no-trailing-spaces": ["warn", { "ignoreComments": true }] , I'm good :)